# djangosaml2 SP and simòlesamlPHP IdP

Tags: django, saml, simplesamlphp, saml-2.0

I have an SP configured with djangosaml2. This authenticates against a simplesamlPHP IdP.
The configuration seems the right one, but the IPD responds that my AuthnRequest should be signed.

This is my djangosaml2 configuration:

```
SAML_CONFIG = {
   # full path to the xmlsec1 binary programm
   'xmlsec_binary': '/usr/bin/xmlsec1',

   # your entity id, usually your subdomain plus the url to the metadata view
   'entityid': 'https://<my_url>/saml2/metadata/',

   # directory with attribute mapping
   'attribute_map_dir': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'attribute-maps'),

   # this block states what services we provide
   'service': {
       'sp' : {
           'name': 'Federated SP',
           'endpoints': {
               'assertion_consumer_service': [
                   ('https://<my_url>/saml2/acs/',
                    saml2.BINDING_HTTP_POST),
                   ],
               'single_logout_service': [
                   ('https://<my_url>/saml2/ls/',
                     saml2.BINDING_HTTP_REDIRECT),

                   ('https://<my_url>/saml2/ls/post',
                    saml2.BINDING_HTTP_POST),
                   ],
               },

            # attributes that this project need to identify a user
           'required_attributes': ['uid'],
           'authn_requests_signed': "true",
           'want_assertions_signed': "true",
           'want_responses_signed': "true",

            # attributes that may be useful to have but not required
           'optional_attributes': [],

           # in this section the list of IdPs we talk to are defined
             'idp': {
               'idpID': {
                   'single_sign_on_service': {
                         saml2.BINDING_HTTP_POST: "https://<their_url>/idp/SSO.saml2",
                     },
                   'single_logout_service': {
                     saml2.BINDING_HTTP_POST: "https://<their_url>/idp/SLO.saml2",
                   },
               },
             },
           },
       },

   # where the remote metadata is stored
   'metadata': {
       'local': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'saml-data/metadata.xml')],
       },

   # set to 1 to output debugging information
   'debug': 1,

   # certificate
   'key_file': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'saml-data/mykey.key'),  # private part
   'cert_file': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'saml-data/mycert.pem'),  # public part


   'valid_for': 24,  # how long is our metadata valid
 }
```

This is my AuthnRequest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<samlp:AuthnRequest xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" AssertionConsumerServiceURL="https://MY_URL/saml2/acs/" Destination="https://THEIR_URL/idp/SSO.saml2" ID="id-438e1715fd5fe61333879b19e2238773" IssueInstant="2015-06-01T15:20:37Z" ProtocolBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Version="2.0">
   <saml:Issuer Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:entity">https://MY_URL/saml2/metadata/</saml:Issuer>
   <ds:Signature Id="Signature1">
      <ds:SignedInfo>
         <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
         <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
         <ds:Reference URI="#id-438e1715fd5fe61333879b19e2238773">
            <ds:Transforms>
               <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
               <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
            </ds:Transforms>
            <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
            <ds:DigestValue>Ool+AyPuBNA1WmBEeOzDZJhLz7Y=</ds:DigestValue>
         </ds:Reference>
      </ds:SignedInfo>
      <ds:SignatureValue>MY_SIGNATURE</ds:SignatureValue>
      <ds:KeyInfo>
         <ds:X509Data>
            <ds:X509Certificate>MY_CERT</ds:X509Certificate>
         </ds:X509Data>
      </ds:KeyInfo>
   </ds:Signature>
   <samlp:NameIDPolicy AllowCreate="false" Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient" />
</samlp:AuthnRequest>
```

And this is IdP's response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<samlp:Response xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" Version="2.0" ID="gBreDljemX37io8bvhlEBeINLUm" IssueInstant="2015-06-01T15:20:53.388Z" InResponseTo="id-438e1715fd5fe61333879b19e2238773" Destination="https://MY_URL/saml2/acs/">
   <saml:Issuer xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">idpdecathlon</saml:Issuer>
   <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
      <ds:SignedInfo>
         <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
         <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
         <ds:Reference URI="#gBreDljemX37io8bvhlEBeINLUm">
            <ds:Transforms>
               <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
               <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
            </ds:Transforms>
            <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
            <ds:DigestValue>f0jH/VawZS9hrx9ErTJfjLGneBM=</ds:DigestValue>
         </ds:Reference>
      </ds:SignedInfo>
      <ds:SignatureValue>STUFF</ds:SignatureValue>
      <ds:KeyInfo>
         <ds:X509Data>
            <ds:X509Certificate>THEIR_CERT</ds:X509Certificate>
         </ds:X509Data>
         <ds:KeyValue>
            <ds:RSAKeyValue>
               <ds:Modulus>MODULUS</ds:Modulus>
               <ds:Exponent>AQAB</ds:Exponent>
            </ds:RSAKeyValue>
         </ds:KeyValue>
      </ds:KeyInfo>
   </ds:Signature>
   <samlp:Status>
      <samlp:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Requester" />
      <samlp:StatusMessage>Signature required</samlp:StatusMessage>
   </samlp:Status>
</samlp:Response>
```

Comment: You might want to add how the simplesamlPHP IDP is configured with access to your public key. If the IDP does not have access to the public key, it cannot recognize the signature. Since the Status Message is optional in the spec and the statuscode simply means there's a problem with the request, it seems possible that the IDP is not able to interpret your signature.

Comment: Hey I am also trying to set up DjangoSAML2 for my project. I do not have any previous experience with SAML. I've gotten the SP side of things set up. But I am having trouble authenticating with idp. Can you please help out? Thanks.